# Ubuntu Crontab to run FTP is not working

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, cron

I want to run an FTP script in Linux server.

Here is my bash file named `transfer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='172.16.0.15'
USER='user'
PASSWD='abc123'

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOF
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
cd /home/user/ftp
mget *
bye
EOF

mv /home/user/*.txt /home/user/ftp/
```

Here is my crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/user/transfer.sh
```

My problem is FTP not running in the crontab, but it is working fine when I execute the bash file using terminal.

Comment: Try these commands.
chkconfig ftp on,
service ftp status

Comment: the ftp is active(running)

Comment: why you are using promote here ? and try get

Comment: I'm sorry but you ask me to check the ftp status right? I've already checked and it's active and running fine.

Comment: change cron timings and try http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php

Comment: i changed it but also nothing happen.

Comment: btw, i found this on syslog. 
Mar 12 14:32:01 ubuntu CRON[4951]: (root) CMD (/home/user/transfer.sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first find out, if the problem is with the shell script or FTP script.

Replace the entry in crontab with:

```
* * * * * /home/user/transfer.sh >>/tmp/transfer.log 2>&1
```

And check the `/tmp/transfer.log` log file for any errors.

---

*You actually need to have the logging (at least stderr) enabled even for a normal operation, not only to debug your current problems.*

---

Though one obvious problem, is that you do not specify a target local directory in your script.

If you run the script manually, the file is downloaded to you current working directory.

But if you run the script in cron, the current working directory is probably the user's home directory, so the script downloads the files there.

You better explicitly specify the working directory:

- either using `cd` command before running `ftp`:

  ```
  cd /local/target/path
  ftp -n -v $HOST << EOF
  ...
  ```
- or using `lcd` command in `ftp` script:

  ```
  lcd /local/target/path 
  mget *
  ```

Comment: so my crontab will be like this? * * * * * /home/user/transfer.sh >>/tmp/transfer.log 2>&1

Comment: ok i've read the log and according to the log, the file has been transfer but i cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: i've append it to my question.

Comment: The file "afiq.txt" is in /home/user/ftp folder of the FTP server. I want to download it to my client pc. If i run the shell script manually, the file afiq.txt is downloaded to my client pc and i can see the file in my client pc. But if I use crontab, as the log shown that the process is completed, but I cannot find the file in my client pc.